# Array.from(object) doesn't convert object into array in my example in React JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I was trying to accept an object and convert it into an array so that I can render it in my react application using a map function. I found that there are two methods to convert the object into an array one using `Array.from(object)` and the second one is `Object.values(object)`. My react application works well when I use the second approach. But If I used the first approach, I got an empty array but when I console log the array's length it is showing the actual length of the array which is 3 in my case.
Moreover, `undefined` values are stored in the array in my case.

Please find the below snippet.

```js
const Example = () => {

let object = {
  productName : "Desktop",
  quantity: 2,
  price: 4000,
  length:3
};

let arr = Array.from(object);

console.log(arr.length);
console.log(arr);

  return ( 
          <div>
              <ul>                  
                {arr.map((item,k) => <li key={k}>{item}</li>)}
              </ul> 
          </div>
         );
};

ReactDOM.render(
    <Example />,document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: `Array.from()` [only turns "Array-likes" (e.g. String, NodeList, etc) into real Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from). It cannot turn arbitrary objects into Arrays. For Objects, you want to use the `Object` utility functions: `Object.keys()`, `Object.values()`, and `Object.entries()` (see MDN for their exact use), all of which yield an array that you can then iterate over using `.map`, or `forEach` or `.some` or `.every` or `reduce` etc.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans just to add - it's for array-likes and also iterators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Array.from` expects a value that has a `length` property and numbered properties for each element. Like this:

```
var arrayLike = {
    0: "hello",
    1: "hello again",
    2: "goodbye",
    length: 3,
};
```

*(Side note: `Array.from` also works on iterables, but that's a whole other story)*

Your object is not like that. You have the `length` property, so it is giving you an array with length 3, but you don't have a `0`, `1`, or `2` property.

If you don't actually need to do anything with the property names (productName, quantity, price), then I think you'd be best off with `Object.values`, but bear in mind that there's also `Object.entries` which allows you to work with the propery names and their values in pairs:

```
{Object.entries(object).map(
    ([key, value]) => <li key={key}>{key} - {value}</li>
)}
```

Comment: Need some example on how `Array.from` also works on iterable. Any useful link that you will recommend to learn the same?

Comment: @SubratoPatnaik https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from